# Rails 3.1 and Heroku - Still not working even with 'therubyracer-heroku'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.1, execjs

I cannot deploy my Rails 3.1rc4 app to Heroku even though I added this to my Gemfile: `gem 'therubyracer-heroku', '0.8.1.pre3', :group => :production`

I can't figure out what the problem is, here is the log: [gist](https://gist.github.com/1085718)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working for me:

```
group :production, :staging do
  gem 'therubyracer', '~> 0.9.3.beta1'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it necessary to list therubyracer in your Gemfile at all?
According to the section towards the bottom of the [Rails 3.1 info on heroku](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar) you are strongly discouraged from using it.

Comment: I posted this when Rails 3.1rc4 was out. Starting with Rails 3.1rc5 Heroku officially started supporting it.

Comment: Yes apologies for raking it up (see what I did there). I didn't notice the date of the original post.